# Counting the number of data occurrences in each pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"E": ["X", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "X"], "F": ["Y", "Y", "X", "Y", "X","Y"], "G": ["Y", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "X"], "I": ["A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A"]})
df.set_index("I", drop = True, inplace = True)

print(df)
   E  F  G
I         
A  X  Y  Y
B  Y  Y  X
B  X  X  X
B  X  Y  X
A  Y  X  Y
A  X  Y  X
```

I want to count now the occurrence of each combination `A-X, A-Y, B-X, B-Y` for each column `E, F, G`, so the expected output would be:

```
       E     F     G
       X  Y  X  Y  X  Y
I                  
A      2  1  1  2  1  2
B      2  1  1  2  3  0
```

I know that I can do it for one column with `pd.crosstab`. So I could iterate through the columns and concatenate the dataframes:

```
for i, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    if i == 0:
        df1 = pd.crosstab(df.index, df[column])
    else:
        df1 = pd.concat([df1, pd.crosstab(df.index, df[column])], axis = 1)
```

But apart from the fact that iteration feels unpandaish and I expect there is a better solution, the index also lost the information regarding the initial columns:

```
       X  Y  X  Y  X  Y
row_0                  
A      2  1  1  2  1  2
B      2  1  1  2  3  0
```

What would be a way to achieve the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) on df and then `groupby` on the indexes and use `sum`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

and you get:

```
   E_X  E_Y  F_X  F_Y  G_X  G_Y
I                              
A    2    1    1    2    1    2
B    2    1    1    2    3    0
```

if you want a multiindex level for the column, you can do:

```
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([col.split('_') for col in df1.columns])
```

and you get as your expected output

Comment: Nice. I have seen get_dummies before, but I have no idea, what it does. Time to have a look it seems.

Comment: @Mr.T thanks for adding the link, I usually do it when it's not commun method but forgot today!